# debconf or perl error during apt-get install

Tags: linux, perl, apt-get, linux-mint, debconf

I use Linux Mint 16 and always get an error when installing a package by apt-get install:

> Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree        Reading
>   state information... Done sqlitebrowser is already the newest version.
>   0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 26 not upgraded. 1 not
>   fully installed or removed. After this operation, 0 B of additional
>   disk space will be used. Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y Use of
>   uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at
>   /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/DbDriver/File.pm line 44, 
>   chunk 3. Use of uninitialized value in -e at
>   /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/DbDriver/File.pm line 46, 
>   chunk 3. Use of uninitialized value in pattern match (m//) at
>   /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/DbDriver/File.pm line 47, 
>   chunk 3. Use of uninitialized value $directory in -d at
>   /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/DbDriver/File.pm line 48, 
>   chunk 3. Use of uninitialized value $directory in concatenation (.) or
>   string at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/DbDriver/File.pm line 49,
>    chunk 3. debconf: DbDriver "config": mkdir :No such
>   file or directory Setting up man-db (2.6.5-2) ... Use of uninitialized
>   value in concatenation (.) or string at
>   /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/DbDriver/File.pm line 44, 
>   chunk 3. Use of uninitialized value in -e at
>   /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/DbDriver/File.pm line 46, 
>   chunk 3. Use of uninitialized value in pattern match (m//) at
>   /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/DbDriver/File.pm line 47, 
>   chunk 3. Use of uninitialized value $directory in -d at
>   /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/DbDriver/File.pm line 48, 
>   chunk 3. Use of uninitialized value $directory in concatenation (.) or
>   string at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/DbDriver/File.pm line 49,
>    chunk 3. debconf: DbDriver "config": mkdir :No such
>   file or directory dpkg: error processing man-db (--configure): 
>   subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit
>   status 1 Errors were encountered while processing:  man-db E:
>   Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Running

```
sudo apt-get install debconf --reinstall
```

or

```
sudo apt-get update --fix-missing
sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get install -f
```

only solved the temporarily(til the next reboot)

Perhaps I have installed perl once, not by using apt-get. I also tried to reinstall perl with synaptic, but it didn't help. What can I do?

Comment: try at http://superuser.com/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've found the problem myself.

I am using an SSD. That's why I mounted /var/cache to RAM(via tmpfs) in order to limit write access on the SSD. Debconf puts it's cache to /var/cache/debconf when installing it. But this is on RAM. So after every restart apt-get only worked if I reinstalled deconf.

Of course the definite solution in this case was to run

> mkdir /var/cache/debconf

in a bootup script.